# What is this multiline string syntax without any string delimiters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This [react example](https://preactjs.com/repl?code=export%20default%20class%20TodoList%20extends%20Component%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20state%20%3D%20%7B%20todos%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20text%3A%20%27%27%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20setText%20%3D%20e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20text%3A%20e.target.value%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20addTodo%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%7B%20todos%2C%20text%20%7D%20%3D%20this.state%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20todos%20%3D%20todos.concat(%7B%20text%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B%20todos%2C%20text%3A%20%27%27%20%7D)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20render(%7B%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20todos%2C%20text%20%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cform%20onSubmit%3D%7Bthis.addTodo%7D%20action%3D%22javascript%3A%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cinput%20value%3D%7Btext%7D%20onInput%3D%7Bthis.setText%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbutton%20type%3D%22submit%22%3EAdd%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20todos.map(%20todo%20%3D%3E%20(%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3E%7Btodo.text%7D%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20))%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fform%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D) has the following multiline string, without ` or any other string delimiters. What's going on here, syntax wise?

```
 render({ }, { todos, text }) {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.addTodo} action="javascript:">
            <input value={text} onInput={this.setText} />
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
            <ul>
                { todos.map( todo => (
                    <li>{todo.text}</li>
                )) }
            </ul>
        </form>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's JSX. I though most introductory React tutorials explained it. There are links that will help on the [Stack Overflow reactjs info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/reactjs/info).

Comment: This is [JSX](https://facebook.github.io/jsx/).

Comment: This might help: http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/jsx

Comment: Ok, so the answer is it's not valid Javascript as it is, just JSX. @nnnnnn or someone, post it as an answer and I'll accept.